# Api для поиска картинок

Tags: android, поиск-api

Есть ли какие api для поиска картинок. Или возможно есть даже стандартные методы.
Находил несколько вариантов, но они все оказались устаревшие.
Хотел бы по запросу находить картинки в интернете и их использовать в качестве иконок внутри приложения.

Comment: Вам точно api нужно? Или что-то типа flaticon.com подойдёт?

Comment: подойдет все что угодно. Например я в бил слово будильник. И на выходе получил то что я мог бы распарсить в ссылки. По которым я бы мог уже скачать несколько изображений с будильниками и предложить на выбор пользователю.